# Is my text indexed by Google?

Tags: javascript, seo

I am making a HTML page, with JavaScript. In the HTML is the first content of a div, but when the user clicks a button, the text changes.

The text in the div is actual content, and needs to be findable by Google. The text is now stored in a simple variable in the JavaScript file.

Questions:
- Is that text indexed?
- Are there any better ways to store the text?

Comment: Open your web page with JavaScript disabled in your browser. This is how Google sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the text in a `div` and then change the visibility to hidden

```
<div id="content" style="visibility: hidden;">
Div content
</div>
```

Then in javascript,

```
document.getElementById("content").style.visibility="visible";
```

should make the document visible. Since the text will be there in the source for the page, it will be indexed by google, but will be displayed only when you run that line of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the text in js variables is generally not a good idea.
You can put this text in a hidden div instead, like this:

```
<div id="target">
    super-text
    ...
</div>

<div id="second">
    super-mega-text
    ...
</div>

<button onclick="replace_text();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function replace_text() {
        var target = document.getElementById('target');
        var second = document.getElementById('second');
        target.innerHTML = second.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

In that case your second text will be indexed by Google.

Of course you better use any js framework like jQuery or Mootools.

Mootools example:

```
<div id="target">
    super-text
    ...
</div>

<div id="second">
    super-mega-text
    ...
</div>

<button id="button">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $('button').addEvent('click', function(){
            $('target').set('html', $('second').get('html'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not searched, see googles answer:
http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?answer=72366

Answer (score 0):

I found a good article about hide/display content only with CSS. It's working without Javascript: http://www.devinrolsen.com/css-hide-and-display-content/

Comment: Thanks, interesting document!